# Server overload: mysql errors

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

My server is overloaded and crashed..

In error_log I have the following error:

```
[29-Jul-2016 18:08:44 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysql_query(): Unable to save result set in /home/site/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1813
```

When server is overloaded the error apear up to 50 times/second.

Do you have any ideea why this is happening?

Comment: just an offhand guess, but maybe because your server is overloaded? if you're having trouble and you KNOW the system is overloaded, the question shouldn't be 'how can I load it up more'.

Comment: A REASON might be that Wordpress sites are notorious for being hammered by bots looking for exploits or weeknesses.  If you are being hammered by the same IP range, I'd set up a firewall policy to block said IP range.

Comment: > Do you have any ideea why this is happening?
We dont have any idea until any error stace trace or code has been posted in your question. Please update the question to find the root casue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is running out of RAM to run the MySQL query.  You can increase the amount of memory a single script may consume by finding your `php.ini` file and changing the `memory_limit` value to a higher number.